# Android ContentProvider with JSON files

Tags: android, json, blob, android-contentprovider, file-transfer

How do I implement a ContentProvider with a JSON file? My goal is wanting the contents of a json file (or the file itself) from one app to be transferred to another app. Android documentation says it can be done with BLOBs but I have no idea what that means, and all of their examples are referring to SQL databases, which my app doesn't use (all data is stored in one JSON file).

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is wanting the contents of a json file (or the file itself) from one app to be transferred to another app.

To literally do this, use `openFile()` on the `ContentProvider` side and `openInputStream()`/`openOutputStream()` on the `ContentResolver` (client) side.

However, I suspect that this is not an especially good idea. JSON is not a data storage model that will work will with multiple simultaneous accessors. IOW, when both apps try to work with the JSON at the same time, who wins and loses?

Also, what happens if the app hosting the JSON file is uninstalled? Now the other app has no more access to the data.

Comment: I mainly need this done for transferring data from a free version of my app to the full paid version. The JSON file keeps an array list of a custom object and I'd like the paid version of my app to inherit this array list. It'll only be a one-time thing.

Comment: @StackOverflowMaster: OK. Here's a sample project showing serving a PDF file on internal storage via a `ContentProvider`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files

Comment: I've looked through your code. Just to clarify, your sample project copies a PDF file, but is it from one app's file directory to another?

Comment: @StackOverflowMaster: You said that you wanted a `ContentProvider` to serve a file. My `ContentProvider` serves a file. It happens to be a PDF, copied out of assets, to simplify the sample, as a file needs to come from *somewhere*. And, my sample happens to be targeting launching an activity to view the file. However, you are perfectly welcome to use `openFile()` to serve a JSON file that you create from whatever you want, and you are welcome to use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` in the other app to read that JSON file, just as PDF viewers do to read my served PDF file.

Comment: Ok so App A provides the file in which I need to open a stream to copy the file over to App B's file directory. My question is, how would I implement that in the receiving app, App B?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks though, your sample code was much appreciated!

Comment: @StackOverflowMaster Come on man, don't be that guy who don't want to help others. If you figured it out, please add it as an answer to your question so that others will be benefited later on.